# Mant-to-many through association in browser RPG game

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a browser RPG text game where the users will have a Hero. This hero will have a Path to choose from..it would work like an RPG class (Wizard, Warrior,etc) (I had to change the name to PAth because Class could not be used).

My models are now set like this:

```
class Hero < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :race
belongs_to :path
end
```

And Path:

```
class Path < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :heros //Need to fix this to Heroes
end
```

Until here, everything works fine. But i wish that the Hero could have skills based on the Hero´s Path.

The Path would have many skills and because the hero is on that Path he would be able to have those skills THROUGH the Path class.... but since he belongs to the class iḿ a little confused.

For instance..the Warrior PAth would have the Bash skill. If the hero is from the Warrior path, he would be able to have this skill also. But these skills would have their own user related atributes...because a user could have a Bash skill with level 1 and another coiuld have it with LVL 2...

So i would like to understand whatś the best approach i could have with this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: don't use "path". that's another pretty meaningful word. anyway, just do as you're doing and do path has_many :skills, and then user can have skills through user.path.skills...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works exactly as you describe:

by creating another class, Skill, which you connect to Path, by putting a

```
has_many: skills
```

in your Path model, you can now access skills through your path:

```
class Hero < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :race
  belongs_to :path

  has_many :skills through: :path
end
```

the way you access them is by writing something like

```
@hero.skills
```

Comment: Would this allow me to have diferente skill attributes(for example: Lvl) for diferent users?

Comment: As it looks now, you have different heroes for different users, and skills are bound to heroes through their path. So you also have different skills for different users

Comment: I mean, for instance..both users can have the same skill, but they can have diferrent levels. Bash lvl1 Bash lvl 2...etc...How can i acess those diferent attributes for each player? Thanks

Comment: If I understand you well, I would say a level belongs to a user? has nothing to do with heroes or paths?

Comment: Let me try to explain. I would have a skill tree based on the path a hero chooses...and based on this path he will be able to have some skills....each skill will have independent hero related variables..for instance lvl, damage, bonus, etc... and each player would have diferent skill levels based on how much he improves the skill... I guess i´m not being very clear..but at least i already got part of my problem solved. =D

Comment: I guess the best you can do is put these hero related variables in your skill class. This way you can increase/decrease a user's skills throughout the game. If you consider your main question answered, can you pls mark the question as "answered"?